# How do we apply chain rule to a function of two variables, which are also functions.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f$ and $g$ be differentiable functions.

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(g(f(x+y),f(z))
$$
How do we apply the chain rule here correctly? Do we just treat $f(x+y)$ and $f(z)$ as some variables $u$ and $v$?

Comment: Look in the index of your calculus book: "chain rule for partial derivatives"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Think of $g = g(u,v)$.  Then, you have $$\frac{\partial}{\partial z}(g(f(x+y),f(z)) = \frac{\partial g}{\partial v}(f(x+y),f(z))f'(z).$$

Comment: Assuming $x,y$ are not functions of $z$.

Comment: Then would $\frac{\partial g}{\partial u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial z} + \frac{\partial g}{\partial v} \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}$ also be correct?

Comment: @MilošRadoman yes, but notice here that $\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = 0$ unless either $x$ or $y$ are non-constant functions of $z$.

Comment: @DMcMor Yes of course, thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

We consider:
\begin{align*}
g=g(u,v)\qquad\qquad &u=u(x,y,z)\\
&v=v(x,y,z)
\end{align*}
In the current situation we have:
\begin{align*}
&u(x,y,z)=f(x+y)\qquad\qquad v(x,y,z)=f(z)\\
&\qquad\ \,\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad\ \  \frac{\partial v}{\partial z}=f^\prime(z)
\end{align*}

> Application of the chain rule gives
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{\partial}{\partial z}g(u(x,y,z),v(x,y,z))&=
> \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}
> +\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial z}\\
> \color{blue}{\frac{\partial}{\partial z}g(f(x+y),f(z))}&\color{blue}{=}
> \frac{\partial g}{\partial u}\, \cdot 0
> +\color{blue}{\frac{\partial g}{\partial v}\,f^{\prime}(z)}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with the already given answer.